# Help needed on Thread.Join()

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0

Here is my scenario.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   List<tasks> listOfTasks =  GetListOfTasks()

   foreach(Task task in Tasks)
   {
      DoSomeWork work = new DoSomeWork();

      Thread workerThread = new Thread(work.CompleteTask());

      workerThread.Start();
   }

   ***How to determine if all threads have finished the task?*** 
}
```

I thought of using CurrentThread.join(). But the current thread will be form_load(). So it will not work.

Any Suggestions on how to determine if all the threads finished their task.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Another option is a CountdownEvent: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.countdownevent.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Okay, now we have more information and know that the question isn't *really* about a user interface, it's easy:

```
List<Task> listOfTasks =  GetListOfTasks()

List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();
foreach(Task task in Tasks)
{
   DoSomeWork work = new DoSomeWork(task);

   Thread workerThread = new Thread(work.CompleteTask);
   workerThread.Start();
   threads.Add(workerThread);
}

// Now all the threads have started, Join on them in turn to wait
// for them to finish. DON'T DO THIS IN A UI THREAD IN A NORMAL APP.
foreach (Thread thread in threads)
{
    thread.Join();
}
```

Of course, using the TPL's `WaitForAll` *is* a better idea than this - if you can use it, do so. But if you're using plain threads, `Join` is fine.

---

EDIT: I've been assuming you're writing a Windows Forms application, based on the Form1_Load method. It would be helpful if you could give more context in the question.

Well, your threads are unlikely to have all finished immediately after you've started them all... and you shouldn't block the UI thread *waiting* for them to finish, as your UI will hang.

Instead, you should make each `DoSomeWork` task call back into the UI when it's finished. Either `DoSomeWork` could have an event you could add a handler to, or you could pass a completion handler delegate into the constructor, or perhaps it knows about the form directly and can call back itself - it depends on what it's doing really.

Anyway, when the task has effectively finished, you can post back to the UI thread using `Control.BeginInvoke`. The form could keep track of how many tasks has finished, so that if it needs to do something when *everything* has finished, it can do so.

If this doesn't help, please give more information about what you want to happen when all the tasks have finished, and what those tasks are doing.

Comment: No I am not working on a Windows Form Application. I am just testing the application which will eventually hosted in a windows serviece. Basically at the form_load() I am getting list of contacts to which I have to make Phone calls. Each phonecall is handled in a thread. Once all the calls are made, I have to invoke a Stored procedure telling that all the calls are made. I am just not sure how I will be able to do that.

Comment: @Sandeep: Oh, well that changes the situation completely. *Please* give more information in future. If you're going to include something talking about forms, you should expect answers that relate to a UI.

Comment: Sorry. I should have did mentioned the complete scenario.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using .NET 4.0 why not taking benefit of TPL:

```
Task.WaitAll(
    listOfTasks.Select(
        item => Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
        {
            DoSomeWork work = new DoSomeWork();
            work.CompleteTask();
        })
    ).ToArray()
);
```

Also if this is ASP.NET you are better off using [asynchronous pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163725.aspx).

Comment: @Jon, that's correct, unfortunately we don't know the OPs scenario (WinForms, ASP.NET, ...) so we cannot offer a better alternative at the moment. You offered one for WinForms (`Control.BeginInvoke`), I offered another one for ASP.NET (asynchronous pages).

Comment: Ooh, I'd been assuming WinForms. Hadn't thought of the idea of an ASP.NET Form_Load.

Comment: @Jon, I think you are closer though as in ASP.NET it's `Page_Load`, not `Form_Load` :-) Anyways, that's why it's better when asking a question to provide such important details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WaitHandle.WaitAll` for waiting for multiple handles - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6w25xa6.aspx

Edit - removed comment about UI thread - since this is asp.net not winforms...

Comment: To expand on SLaks' comment: 1) it won't work because the UI thread will be (or should be) an STAThread; 2) you don't want to block the UI thread anyway.

Comment: Totally agree - 99.999% of the time anyway - and I was just updating the answer... however, just checking the use of WaitHandle with Thread - not sure it wants to be used that way... so might scrub the answer (it's good to learn these things!)

Comment: P.S. I'm assuming `Task` in this question is *not* from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx

Comment: @stuart It has nothing to do with the link you posted. It is just imaginary task.

Comment: @sandeep - that's what I thought - it's worth looking at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx for the future - tasks look like they are even more relevant in C#5

Answer (score 0):

```
void Main()
{
    var spooler = new Spooler();
    Random r = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        var work = new DoSomeWork { Delay = r.Next(100, 5000) };
        spooler.Add(work);
    }
    spooler.Poll(100);
    Logger.Log("finish");
}
static class Logger
{
    internal static void Log(string msg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} says " + msg, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }
}
public class Spooler
{
    private object _lock = new object();
    private List<DoSomeWork> _workItems = new List<DoSomeWork>();
    public void Add(DoSomeWork work)
    {
        _workItems.Add(work);
        Action whenDone = () => { lock(_lock) work.Done = true; };
        (new Thread(()=>work.CompleteTask(whenDone))).Start();        
    }
    public void Poll(int rate)
    {
        while(true)
        {
            var q = from c in _workItems
                    where c.Done == false
                    select c;
            Logger.Log("poll");
            int count = -1;
            lock(_lock)
            {       
                if(q.FirstOrDefault() == null) break;
                count = q.Count();
            }
            Logger.Log(count + " to go");
            Thread.Sleep(rate);
        }
    }
}
public class DoSomeWork
{
    public bool Done = false;
    public int Delay { get; set; }
    public void CompleteTask(Action whenDone)
    {
        Logger.Log("begin " + Delay);
        Thread.Sleep(Delay);
        Logger.Log("end");
        whenDone();
    }
}

15 says begin 2707
21 says begin 2809
12 says begin 4586
27 says begin 4822
28 says begin 242
29 says begin 2989
30 says begin 1374
31 says begin 4265
32 says begin 2679
33 says begin 4041
14 says poll
14 says 10 to go
14 says poll
14 says 10 to go
14 says poll
14 says 10 to go
28 says end
14 says poll
14 says 9 to go
14 says poll
14 says 9 to go
14 says poll
14 says 9 to go
14 says poll
14 says 9 to go
14 says poll
14 says 9 to go
14 says poll
14 says 9 to go
14 says poll
14 says 9 to go
14 says poll
14 says 9 to go
14 says poll
14 says 9 to go
14 says poll
14 says 9 to go
14 says poll
14 says 9 to go
30 says end
14 says poll
14 says 8 to go
14 says poll
14 says 8 to go
14 says poll
14 says 8 to go
14 says poll
14 says 8 to go
14 says poll
14 says 8 to go
14 says poll
14 says 8 to go
14 says poll
14 says 8 to go
14 says poll
14 says 8 to go
14 says poll
14 says 8 to go
14 says poll
14 says 8 to go
14 says poll
14 says 8 to go
14 says poll
14 says 8 to go
14 says poll
14 says 8 to go
32 says end
14 says poll
14 says 7 to go
15 says end
14 says poll
14 says 6 to go
21 says end
14 says poll
14 says 5 to go
29 says end
14 says poll
14 says 4 to go
14 says poll
14 says 4 to go
14 says poll
14 says 4 to go
14 says poll
14 says 4 to go
14 says poll
14 says 4 to go
14 says poll
14 says 4 to go
14 says poll
14 says 4 to go
14 says poll
14 says 4 to go
14 says poll
14 says 4 to go
14 says poll
14 says 4 to go
14 says poll
14 says 4 to go
33 says end
14 says poll
14 says 3 to go
14 says poll
14 says 3 to go
31 says end
14 says poll
14 says 2 to go
14 says poll
14 says 2 to go
14 says poll
14 says 2 to go
12 says end
14 says poll
14 says 1 to go
14 says poll
14 says 1 to go
14 says poll
14 says 1 to go
27 says end
14 says poll
14 says finish
```